# Como colorir Eventos no FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

colorir eu consigo, mas preciso colorir ao selecionar o vendedor X, Como colorir diferentes Eventos no fullcalendar? baseado em um option... exemplo: tenho 3 vendedores, quero que cada Vendedor tenha sua cor própria ao clicar no dia para cadastrar um evento, isso ele escolhe através de um modal. Esse modal é a tela de cadastro do Evento, onde o vendedor escolhe o Titulo, o nome do Vendedor, a data inicial e a data final.... quando escolher o vendedor A a cor no fullcalendar deve ser vermelha, quando escolher o Vendedor B a cor deve ser azul e quando escolher o Vendedor C a cor deve ser verde... desde já muito obrigado...

```
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Salesman</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color">
    <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">ERICK</option>
    <option style="color:#0071c5;" value="#0071c5">MATHEUS</option>
    <option style="color:#FF4500;" value="#FF4500">JÉSSICA</option>
    </select>
    </div>

<div class="modal-body">
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>ID do Evento</dt>
    <dd id="id"></dd>
    <dt>Titulo do Evento</dt>
    <dd id="title"></dd>
    <dt>Vendedor</dt>
    <dd id="color"></dd>
    <dt>Inicio do Evento</dt>
    <dd id="start"></dd>
    <dt>Fim do Evento</dt>
    <dd id="end"></dd>
</dl>
</div>

eventClick: function(event) {
    $('#visualizar #id').text(event.id);
    $('#visualizar #title').text(event.title);
    $('#visualizar #color').text(event.color);
    //$('#visualizar #vend').text(event.vend);
    $('#visualizar #start').text(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')); 
    $('#visualizar #end').text(event.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')); 
    $('#visualizar').modal('show');
return false; },
```

Comment: Mostre seu código.

Comment: AQUI O USUÁRIO ESCOLHE O VENDEDOR, até ai tudo bem, o evento vai pro calendário na cor especificada
<div class="form-group">
         <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vendedor</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color">
           <option value="">Selecione</option>   
           <option style="color:#0071c5;" value="#0071c5">ERICK</option>
           <option style="color:#FF4500;" value="#FF4500">JÉSSICA</option>
           <option style="color:#8B4513;" value="#8B4513">MATHEUS</option>
</select>

Comment: AQUI É O EVENTO, que puxa no BD:
events: [
      <?php
       while($row_events = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_events)){
        ?>
        {
        id: '<?php echo $row_events['id']; ?>',
        title: '<?php echo $row_events['title']; ?>',
        start: '<?php echo $row_events['start']; ?>',
        end: '<?php echo $row_events['end']; ?>',
        color: '<?php echo $row_events['color']; ?>',
        },<?php
       }
      ?>
     ]

Comment: AQUI É ONDE MOSTRA O EVENTO em um modal, e é aqui o problema, não mostra o Vendedor, se eu coloco pra mostrar o Vendedor, ele pára de colorir.:

Comment: $('#visualizar #id').text(event.id);
      $('#visualizar #id').val(event.id);
      
      $('#visualizar #title').val(event.title);
      
      $('#visualizar #start').val(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
      $('#visualizar 
      $('#visualizar #end').val(event.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
      $('#visualizar #color').val(event.color);
      //$('#visualizar #color').text(event.color);
      $('#visualizar').modal('show');

Comment: E AQUI É O MODAL ONDE MOSTRA O EVENTO:
<div class="visualizar">
       <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>ID</dt>
        <dd id="id"></dd>
        <dt>Cliente</dt>
        <dd id="title"></dd>
        <dt>Vendedor</dt>
        <dd id="color"></dd>
        <dt>Inicio previsto</dt>
        <dd id="start"></dd>
        <dt>Fim previsto</dt>
        <dd id="end"></dd>
       </dl>
       <button class="btn btn-canc-vis btn-warning">Editar</button>
      </div>

Comment: @NetinhoSantos  ai estão meus códigos.

Comment: Insira seu código na pergunta. Fica mais fácil ler

Comment: @NetinhoSantos coloquei na pergunta o código.

Comment: @André Baill , consegue me ajudar,?

Comment: @Felipe Miranda de Lima

Comment: Não sei se é exatamente o que tu queres, mais aqui vai um exemplo: http://jsbin.com/cuninamula/edit?html,output . Só não consegui colocar aqui no Stack, ele não carregava a lib do FullCalendar :( Caso seja, poderei colocar o código na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se compreendi bem o que queres mais segue um exemplo.

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: [{
      id: '01',
      title: 'event1',
      start: '2018-06-25'
    },
    {
      id: '02',
      title: 'event2',
      start: '2018-06-25',
      end: '2018-06-26'
    },
    {
      id: '03',
      title: 'event3',
      start: '2018-06-25',
    }
  ],
  eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#ModalId').val(event.id);
    $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
    $('#calendarModal').modal();
  },

});
$('#color').change(function(events) {
  var id = $('#ModalId').val();
  var ev = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('clientEvents', id);
  ev[0].backgroundColor = $(this).val();
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fullcalendar/1.5.4/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fullcalendar/1.5.4/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="calendar"></div/>

  <div id="calendarModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
          <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">
          <input type="hidden" id="ModalId" />
          <div class="row">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Salesman</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color">
                <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">ERICK</option>
                <option style="color:#0071c5;" value="#0071c5">MATHEUS</option>
                <option style="color:#FF4500;" value="#FF4500">JÉSSICA</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```